# Blazor Server Side Console.WriteLine not working

Tags: blazor

On a server side Blazor app I am finding that `Console.WriteLine` does not work. Why can't I see the text in Chrome Console?

```
@code{

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() 
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("oninit");
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case I was using Console.Write("...") which did not work.  Console.WriteLine("...") seemed to work though.  Not sure why both wouldn't write to the browser console.

Answer (score 29):

I had to do something like this to make text show in the browser console:

```
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

@code {

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("console.log", "hello world");
    }
}
```

Comment: For people using the server-side hosting model: You can test this using `OnAfterRenderAsync` instead of `OnInitializedAsync`.

Comment: Only InvokeVoidAsync - What do you want a return for?

Answer (score 16):

When you run it under IIS Express there is indeed no output.

You can use the dropdown on the Run button to select your application by name instead of IIS.  And then you will see your output in the console window.

Or use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print()` to see it in the Output Window.

> I mean I can't see the text in Chrome Console.

That only happens with Client Side (WebAssembly) Blazor.

Comment: Or you can choose your project in the "Show output from" dropdown in VS Output window to see the console messages...if you are using IIS Express and want to see Console.WriteLine messages.

Comment: Great will try. Thanks

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print() is the only one that worked for me.  Shows up in Visual Studio Output tab with Showing output from Debug.

Answer (score 9):

You can see in your output window that Console.WriteLine outputs to your app ASP.NET Core Web Server when you are running through IIS Express or as your application.
From IIS Express
[image of IIS Express Output Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oofa8.png)

As your Application
[image of running though your application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiYIP.png)
[image of your application Output Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1060q.png)

If you want to write to your web console you need to work in Client Side Blazor. 
This is discussed [on github discussion page](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/7124)

Comment: Also make shure, that you have <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script> on your page. I faced this problem when I tried to make blazor project template as simple as possible, I deleted layout, menu, header component, css styles etc. I forgot to add the script to my single Index page, so the Console.WriteLine did not work. – 
Eugene Maksimov

Answer (score 5):

Writing messages in the browser developer tools console. Ueful on Blazor Server. In Blazor WASM we can use Console.WriteLine(), or this same strategy.

```cs
@page "/sample-log"
@inject IJSRuntime _js

<!-- html -->

@code {
    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Log("Initialized"); // test
    }

    async ValueTask Log(string text)
    {
        await _js.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

How to view “Console Output” (i.e.  Console.WriteLine statements) for a Blazor App:

- Go to the Output tab within Visual Studio
- In the “Show Output from:” drop-down, select your app instead of “Debug”
- This will now enable you to see any of your Console.Writeline statements to appear now in the Output window within Visual Studio

(This was tested in Visual Studio 2019)

Comment: I dont have the app name in the dropdown at all. The output used to work, but suddenly, stopped working. Both Console.WriteLine and System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine are gone; not in the Output window and neither in the console window. Running VS 2019 16.9.4  (latest version as of right now).

Comment: ... before I had printout in VS (output window or console window). Now I discovered them in the web browser console instead....

Comment: make this one as answer please

Answer (score 2):

Use System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(), you'll see the result in the output window of Visual Studio, dropdown "debug". If you want to see the result in the browser's console window see the other answers already given.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed for server-side blazor this is not working,

[image]

Change from Debug to your app name in the dropdown to see your console output:

[image]