# Where I can find the Console.WriteLine output from the Blazor Server App?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, console-output

I have the Blazor component library, I need to debug it. The library can be used in Blazor WASM and Blazor Server-Side Apps. For debug purposes I do some console output:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello!")
```

In the Blazor WASM app I can see it in the Browser Console.

Where can I see it in case of Blazor Server-Side App?
Is using of the Debug.WriteLine method the only way to see the output? Is there a common way to write debug information for both Blazor WASM and Server-Side?

PS: There is no Console output in Debug window in case of Blazor Server-Side App.

Comment: In the web app's console. The web app is still a console application so even when debugging a console window is shown. It may be hidden by other windows. Use logging if you want to control where the messages are written.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If "IIS Express" is selected for debugging than the console window does not show up. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57750887/blazor-server-side-console-writeline-not-working

Comment: @maciek which is why `Console.WriteLine` should be avoided. It's still possible to write the standard output to a file through a `web.config` setting but that's really only useful when the web app can't even start

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know it should be avoided, but Eugene Maksimov still wanted to use it.

Comment: In that case the answer is to configure StdOut redirection, not the Debug Window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.NET6**

If you are using Visual Studio on Windows, try selecting the name of the project when debugging Blazor Server App.

[image: https://ibb.co/MpnG7qT]

A console window will open and this is where your standard output is redirected. Anything you output from Console.WriteLine is shown there. What you write with Console.WriteLine is output to a standard output. In case of Linux app this would be terminal output.

**.NET7**

There are new options. If you select http or https in the same menu the console will appear (VS 17.9.3)

[image: .NET]

Comment: Something changed, then. The project name doesn't show up in that dropdown (anymore). This worked on VS2022 in the past, not sure why it's no longer there.
The options now are http, https, IIS Express, and WSL.  Does this not work with Blazor Server apps in dotnet7 ?

Comment: @MC9000 If you make your Blazor Server App in .NET6 you still have the options I show. It does not work with .NET7. You have the options as you mentiond. If you run https, the console window appears.

Answer (score 0):

I wondered where that output window went. Maciek's answer is correct! thanks!

[image: Microsoft Visual Studio Debug Console]